# MySQL select by mask

Tags: mysql, select, match

There is a MySQL table with content like this:

```
id mask
1  abcd
2  vdskfw
...
212421 dijhaihwfaw
```

I have an incoming string, for example, **abcd**efghijkl, and I need to check, if it begins with any match from the table.
I can do it with multiple queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mask = 'abcdefghijkl';
```

if no match:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mask = 'abcdefghijk';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mask = 'abcdefghij';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mask = 'abcdefghi';
```

...and so on.

But maybe there is a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: use `LIKE` and if necessary regex

Comment: How?  I could use LIKE if mysql content were haystack and incoming string were needle. But it's the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these will do what you asked for.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE locate(mask, 'abcdefghijkl') = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 'abcdefghijkl' rlike concat('^', mask)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 'abcdefghijkl' like concat(mask, '%')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd970/19)